# How Make Server Name and Database Name Dynamic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, parameters

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

--,@DBName              VARCHAR(30)
--SET @jobNumber=417133 
--SELECT @DBName = DataBaseName,'tdis', @server = '[' + isnull(server,'s-portaldb1') + ']' 
--from tdLogging.dbo.tblJobDbLookup where jobnumber = @jobNumber
DROP TABLE #Actual

CREATE TABLE #Actual (
    jobnumber INT
    ,firstNameCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,lastNameCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,address1Counts VARCHAR(25)
    ,address2Counts VARCHAR(25)
    ,cityCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,stateCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,zipCounts VARCHAR(25)
    ,inHomeDateCounts VARCHAR(25)
    )

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #actual (jobnumber,firstNameCounts,lastNameCounts , address1Counts, address2Counts, cityCounts, stateCounts, zipCounts, inHomeDateCounts) '
SET @sql = @sql + ' Select s.jobnumber, count(s.firstName) AS [firstNameCounts], Count (s.lastName) AS [lastNameCounts], Count (s.Address1) As [address1Counts], Count (s.address2)-Count (address2) AS '
SET @sql = @sql + ' [address2Counts], Count (s.City) AS [cityCounts], Count (s.State) AS [stateCounts], Count (s.Zip) AS [zipCounts], Count (jb.inHomeDate) AS [inHomeDateCounts] '
SET @sql = @sql + ' From [s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133].[dbo].[tblStandardFinal] s '
SET @sql = @sql + ' INNER JOIN [s-printstream].[tdSchedule2].[dbo].[tblJobTicketActions] jb '
SET @sql = @sql + ' ON jb.psFlagJobNumber = s.jobNumber '
SET @sql = @sql + ' where jobNumber = @jobNumber '
SET @sql = @sql + ' group by jobNumber '

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    ,N'@JobNumber Varchar(25)'
    ,@JobNumber = 417133;

SELECT *
FROM #Actual
```

I am trying to get this code to run dynamically and i wanted to have the "[s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133]" come on the run means dynamically.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I know what  "come on the run" means, but if you are trying to make the server name dynamic in your dynamic SQL, just add a parameter for your server name and then introduce that to your SQL using something like the following:

```
DECLARE @ServerName varchar(100) = '[s-portaldb1].[tdis_417133]'

SET @sql = @sql + ' From ' + @Servername + '.[dbo].[tblStandardFinal] s '
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for and i will try to implement that and see how that works..